# How to get cell row and column(or address) of a stored variable? / Or how to .select/.activate cell of a stored variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a part of vba code:

```
 Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, rng1 As Range
    Dim highestValue As Double

    Set rng = Range("E3:E5489")
    Set rng1 = rng.Offset(0, 1)
    highestValue = 0

    For Each cell In rng1
    If cell.value > highestValue Then highestValue = cell.value
    Next cell

End Sub
```

So, how can I find the variable's "highestValue" row num and column num, so I can later refer from it to offset to another column?
Or, how can I make THAT cell active? 
I've tried to find methods, but it seems to only be possible with defined range, etc. 
So, maybe even set that cell as range? Is that possible somehow? I haven't been able to find it.
Please help :)

Comment: Just make `highestValue` a `Range` instead of a `Double`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys for your help, I really appreciate it!

I knew it was a simple solution, but since I'm new in vba, I wasn't able to find it...

Thanks to guys who posted, here's the solution:

1. Define a range

   `Dim MaxCell As Range
    Dim week1 As Range`
2. Create If loop inside For Each loop:

   `For Each cell In rng1
           If cell.Value > highestValue Then
               highestValue = cell.Value
               Set MaxCell = cell
           End If
       Next cell`

   `Set week1 = MaxCell.Offset(0, -1)`
3. Add to cell/range:

   `Range("H2").Value = week1`

So you get the corresponding cell value of the highest value.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, rng1 As Range
    Dim highestValue As Double, MaxCell As Range

    Set rng = Range("E3:E5489")
    Set rng1 = rng.Offset(0, 1)

    highestValue = 0

    For Each cell In rng1
        If cell.Value > highestValue Then
            highestValue = cell.Value
            Set MaxCell = cell
        End If
    Next cell

    MsgBox MaxCell.Address(0, 0) & vbCrLf & highestValue
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, mate, it's a huge contribute!

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Match(highestvalue,ActiveSheet.Range("F:F"),0),6).Address(0,0)
```

To the last line.  It will spit out the address.